# How to create partial invoice using rest API in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, partial-invoice

I have one order, this order is having 3 items. I want to create different invoices of different items using Rest API. It is possible using the admin panel in Magento-2.1, but not using rest API. How to create a partial invoice?

Comment: anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this endpoint

> POST /V1/order/{order id}/invoice

the json should be

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": {item_id},
      "qty": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

the **item id** is the item id of the product in the order

Comment: I will use this API,but it is show wrong details.Suppose I have two items in order,one is simple product and other is bundle product.When i generate invoice of simple product,then it show simple product information as well as bundle product parent item detail . It show in screenshot as below:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vteo6.png

Comment: anybody guide me.

Comment: what is the type of your bundle product, is it Fixed or Dynamic?

Comment: Bundle Product-Dynamic

Comment: please have a look at this wiki, i could not write the whole text here, http://wikicoode.com/magento2/create-invoice-rest-api-magento2-bundle-product

Comment: I have 2 products in order,one is simple product and other is bundle product.Firstly i will create invoice with simple product item id.It show in screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi6L3.png. @WISAM HAKIM

Comment: please have a look at this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecdsg.png .

Comment: from the screenshot, i see that your code is correct (you invoice the simple product)

Comment: Yes,I will generate invoice for simple product.But it show bundle product parent item information.I could not found what is issue in this @WISAM HAKIM.